# How to get first word from text file removing \n - python

Tags: python

If the text file is  `/n/n        Hello world!/n I like python./n`
How do I get the first word from that text?
I tried to code:

```
def word_file(file):
    files = open(file, 'r')
    l = files.readlines()
    for i in range(len(l)):            
        a = l[i].rstrip("\n")
        line = l[0]
        word = line.strip().split(" ")[0]
    return word
```

There is space in front Hello.
The result I get is NONE. How should I correct it? 
Can anybody help?

Comment: You put `line = l[0]` which evaluates to an empty string

Comment: You process all lines instead of only the first containing 'something' so any result is that of the last line only.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there *is* a word in the file:

```
def word_file(f):
    with open(f) as file:
        return file.read().split()[0]
```

`file.read` reads the entire file as a string. Do a `split` with no parameters on that string (i.e. `sep=None`). Then according to the Python manual "runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace." So the splitting will be done on consecutive white space and there will be no empty strings returned as a result of the split. Therefore the first element of the returned list will be the first word in the file.

If there is a possibility that the file is empty or contains nothing but white space, then you would need to check the return value from `file.read().split()` to ensure it is not an empty list.

If you need to avoid having to read the entire file into memory at once, then the following, less terse code can be used:

```
def word_file(f):
    with open(f) as file:
        for line in file:
            words = line.split()
            if words:
                return words[0]
        return None # No words found
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: @Booboo answer is far better than my answer**

This should work:

```
def word_file(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for index, character in enumerate(line):
                if not character.isspace():
                    line = line[index:]
                    for ind, ch in enumerate(line):
                        if ch.isspace():
                            return line[:ind]
                    return line # could not find whitespace character at end
        return None # no words found
```

output:

```
Hello
```

Comment: The example the OP shows has `Hello` after the initial white space, which is composed of alpha characters. But the the OP in his coding effort is looking for whatever non-white space there is. Now maybe there will never be anything but alpha in that position. But couldn't the text begin with `1961 was the year that John F. Kennedy was inaugurated President of the United States.`? You would not find 1961.

Comment: Or just go all the way with `if not character.isspace():` Also, isn't `space_index = line.find(' ', index)` better than `space_index = line.find(' ', line.find(character))`? But that raises yet another question. Now you are looking for only a space character following the first word. But what if it is terminated by some other whitespace character? I hope you take these comments in the spirit in which they are offered.

Comment: I modified your code incorporating the changes discussed ensuring the file is closed when done and avoiding having to read the file in all at once, which is an optimization.